# Deployment a Flow Builder by changeset

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment

Iam unable to deploy a Flow Builder to production and getting below error.
Update_MQL_Date (Update Records) - When the inputAssignments field is set, the sObjectInputReference field isn't supported.
And i able to deploy this flow builder one sandbox to another sandbox. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hi KarthikReddy, Can you confirm in which release version is sandbox and production?

Comment: Hello SaiPraveen, Production version is 55 and Sandbox is 56. Is this reason for failing?

Comment: Are you using the new functionality "Update records related to the record that triggered the flow" in the flow?

Comment: Yes, Iam updating contact record from Campaign Member

Comment: This is a new feature in Winter23 sandbox. This behaviour is not present in Summer22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you confirmed in comments that you are using the new feature of Flows **"Update records related to the record that triggered the flow"** in the update Element.

This feature is newly introduced in [Winter23](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_update_related_records.htm&type=5&release=240). As your sandbox is Winter23 sandbox you have that feature. Still production Orgs are not migrated to Winter23 and they are still Summer 22.  Salesforce will upgrade the production orgs  starting from this weekend till October 24 based on your instance.

if you want the same flow to work in production you need to wait till the production is Winter23. Else you have to modify your flow and include logic to add get records and update them.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you mentioned that your sandbox is on a Winter 23 preview instance, and your production org is on Summer 22. This mismatch can happen during the sandbox preview period leading up to a new release.

Most of the time, this is fairly easy to resolve. Each Flow can be defined to use a specific version. When you create a new Flow, it will automatically use the latest version in that org, so your Flow is using v56, along with the new updates that version brings. You can change the version your Flow uses in the Flow Builder, in the gear icon settings menu where you can set properties like the label and description of the Flow. Click Advanced to see more properties, and set the Flow Version back from 56 to 55.

If your Flow isn't using any new or changed features unavailable in Summer, you just need to save and activate this new version of the Flow with the updated API version, and upload a new change set.

If you were using new or changed features, you'll either need to refactor your Flow to not use these features, or wait until your production instance gets the upgrade.

I suspect that `sObjectInputReference` is related to the new capability to select a child or parent relationship to update in an update element, rather than needing to define a filter that matches on an Id value. If that's the case, and if you are using this capability, you'll need to update your Flow to use a filter that matches on Id, or wait until the production release.

In rare cases, even updating your Flow to the prior version and not using new or updated features can still have issues, but that is rare and is considered a bug when it happens.